# Shiny: use validate() inside downloadHandler

Tags: shiny

I have a Shiny app which prints a report once a button is clicked. The report creation happens via the downloadHandler() function.

I would like to have a compulsory input field before the report can be exported; the appropriate Shiny function is validate() (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html).

However, according to the documentation, the validate() function can only be used in reactive() or render() functions:

```
To use this validation test in your app, place it at the start of any reactive or render* expression that calls input$data.
```

I do not find a place where I can put this function in my downloadHandler function. Does anybody know how this is possible?

Here is the relevant code part; I want the field "company_name" to be compulsory for the creation of the report.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    position = "left",

    sidebarPanel(

      textInput(
        inputId = "company_name",
        label = "Company name", 
        value = ""
      ),
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.pdf",
    content = function(file) {
      # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
      # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
      # can happen when deployed).
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      dir.create(file.path(tempdir(),"www"))
      file.copy("www", file.path(tempdir()), recursive=TRUE)      

      # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
      params <- list(company_name = input$company_name)

      # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
      # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
      # from the code in this app).

      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that a `downloadButton` is an input widget and `validate` is supposed to be used with outputs.

My workaround would be to hide (or disable) the `downloadButton` if your requirements for downloading are not met. This can be done with `shinyjs`, which allows you to hide or disable buttons by id.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  textInput("text", "content", "", placeholder = "please insert something"),
  shinyjs::hidden(downloadButton("download"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "file.csv",
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data.frame(content = input$text), file)
    }
  )

  observeEvent(input$text, {
    if (input$text == "")
      shinyjs::hide("download")
    else
      shinyjs::show("download")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Replace `hide/show/hidden` with `enable/disable/disabled` to show the button all the time but make it unclickable whenever `input$text` is empty.

Comment: Please, use "shinyjs::" prefix for shinyjs::hide/show("download") lines of code.

Comment: @Andrii done! I do not attach the `shinyjs` package in the new version of the answer. Did you experience any namespace conflicts with `hide()` and `show()` in the past?

Comment: I just found that for me it works with "shinyjs::" prefix only. Thanks for advice!

Comment: That's odd. You probably have some other package attached that overrides the definition of `hide()` and/or `show()`. You could use the CRAN package `conflicted` to diagnose this further.