# validate within downloadHandler - avoid file to be generated

Tags: r, shiny

**Background**

I have a `reactive` which is used *both* for rendering output but also in a `downloadHandler`. Within this `reactive` I use `validate` to signal to the `render*` function if there is something amiss. However, this creates problems in the `downloadHandler`. In the app below, if the input is not validated the browser shows "HTTP 500 Internal Server Error" (IE) or a "Failed - Server Problem" (Chrome) - cf. screenshots.

*Chrome*
[image: Server Failed]

*IE*
[image: HTTP 500]

**Desired Outcome**

I would like to find a way to avoid this behavior in the first place. I have read [Validate inside downloadHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903285/validate-inside-downloadhandler) and [Shiny: use validate() inside downloadHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53616176/shiny-use-validate-inside-downloadhandler) and both recommend to hide/change the download button if there is an issue. So how would an `observer` looks like, which fires whenever the `reactive` is invalid?

*Note.*  It is *not* possible to change/adapt the `reactive` itself as it is encapsulated in a module and the module has no access to my `downloadHandler`.

**Code**

```
library(shiny)

testUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  numericInput(ns("n"), "n", 0, -3, 3)
}

test <- function(input, output, session) {
  r <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$n >= 0, "value is smaller than zero"))
    as.character(input$n)
  })
  list(reactive_i_cannot_change_because_the_code_does_not_belong_2_me = r)
}


ui <- fluidPage(testUI("my_module"), 
                downloadLink('downloadData', 'Download')
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  handler <- callModule(test, "my_module")

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('data-', Sys.Date(), '.txt', sep='')
    },
    content = function(con) {
      writeLines(
        isolate(
           handler$reactive_i_cannot_change_because_the_code_does_not_belong_2_me()
        ), 
        con)
    }
  )

  observe({
    ## if i could react whenever handler$reactive...() is invalid
    ## I could simply hide the download button here
    ## Things that did not work: 
    ##   - tryCatch(handler$reactive...(), ...) 
    ##   - if (is.null(handler$reactive...())
  })
}
```

Comment: Why don't you test `if(is.null(r()){ "hide the button" }`

Comment: Thx, but this does not work. I guess that `validate` raises an error and this is somehow captured differently in the shiny context.

Comment: Then why not returning `NULL` in `r` when `input$n < 0`, instead of using `validate` ?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the `reactives` in my real case - the `downloadHandler` sits in a module which takes other modules as parameter and I have little control over the `reactives` from these modules.

Comment: And why not directly `if(input$n < 0){ "hide the button" }` ?

Comment: I abstracted the problem too much in my reprex. I will change that to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. While `tryCatch` did not work as intended, I found a solution with `try`:

```
observe({
  res <- try(handler$reactive_i_cannot_change_because_the_code_does_not_belong_2_me(), TRUE)
  if ("try-error" %in% class(res)) {
    print("disable")
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `show` and `hide` functions from `shinyjs` package -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  numericInput("n", "n", 0, -3, 3), 
  downloadLink('downloadData', 'Download')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  r <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$n >= 0, "value is smaller than zero"))
    as.character(input$n)
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('data-', Sys.Date(), '.txt', sep='')
    },
    content = function(con) {
      writeLines(isolate(r()), con)
    }
  )

  observe({
    ## if i could react whenever r() is invalid
    ## I could simply hide the download button here
    ## tryCatch(r(), ...) did not work
    if(input$n < 0) {
      hide(id = "downloadData")
    } else {
      show(id = "downloadData")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I figured that I made my original post too abstracted from my real problem, pleas see the update. In principal I have only the reactive in my main application and I cannot access inputs directly. _Only_ the `reactive`.